# Django, List of related field's attribute as queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Article(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

for a given reporter, I'd like to get `reporter.article_set.all().values('book')` as Book queryset instead of valuesQueryset.

Is it possible to turn `Article.objects.all().values('book')` into Book queryset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want books, start with Book.

```
Book.objects.filter(article__reporter=reporter)
```

Comment: how do you detect these juicy questions so fast, @daniel?

Comment: so `Article.objects.all().values('book') into Book queryset` cant't easily done, right?

Comment: @eugene no, a values call can never return an actual queryset.